# Alternate for %TYPE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

In Oracle we create variables using **%TYPE** so that the variable has the same data type as the column's data type.

example

```
c_FolderType Folder.FolderType%TYPE;
c_FolderYear Folder.FolderYear%TYPE;
```

May I know how do I handle it in SQL Server. Do we have a similar option in SQL Server or the only option is to manually assign a data type

Comment: You would need to define the data type, as you need to `DECLARE` the variable before you can assign to it. Though the `sql_variant` data type does exist, it's use is not recommended as it comes with (a lot of) caveats and still requires you to define the typing at some point.

Comment: Side note, SQL Server 2008 has been out of support for over a year; if that is the version you are moving to I suggest getting it upgraded before you do so. 2012 is only in Extended support as well, so you should still do the same with that.

Comment: @Larnu - thanks for the side note, we are using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Then you shouldn't really have tagged [tag:sql-server-2008] and  [tag:sql-server-2012] when you posted your question. Fortunately Joel removed them, but tagging old versions of product, especially when you're using far more recent ones, is only to your detriment. Always ensure you tag properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a language extension that is not a standard (ansi) part of SQL. Sql Server does not do this, and requires you to set the type manually.